# Liberty SSL Certificate Key not working anymore

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have an app hosted in Bluemix (Liberty instance) with a ssl certificate with bluepages for the login.

The login has been working fine for 2 years, until today.
It throws the following error:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

Perhaps my key.jks stopped working, but i'm not managing to get a new one.
I need help with that.
Thanks!

EDIT: When i downloaded the previous certificate (the one that expired) i did it from a bluemix forum, but i cant find the way to download the new LDAP certificate for liberty. The file was called something like this "bluepages.com.cert".

Comment: Has anything changed like a software upgrade, or  a JVM upgrade?  Has your key/certificate expired?

Comment: No, i dont think so. I forgot to mention that locally, with an instance of websphere application server, i have the same issue, so it probably is that the key has expired, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"bluepages" got a new certificate with a new root CA this last weekend. You need to update your trust store with the new root.